# Knockout js - If one dependent observable gets executed all the other dependent observables in that class gets executed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout Js..I have this issue on my page that when one dependent observable is getting executed, an unrelated dependent observable also gets executed.

Is this a normal behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only related dependent observables should be executed.

Knockout.js will retrieve the initial value of the dependent observable and it will monitor what obervables were accessed. Then it will subscribe to those observables to detect future changes.

If a observable changes that is not related to your dependent observable then it shouldn't be executed.

See: [How dependency tracking works](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

If you want further help then include an code example. Also make sure  you are running the latest Knockout.js version with bug fixes, etc.